# When finding the refractive index of a glass block should the graph be forced through the origin or not?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, refraction, data-analysis

Experiment: To measure the refractive index of a block of glass.

A block of glass is placed on a sheet of paper and the outline is drawn. A point of incidence is chosen and the normal at the point of incidence is drawn. Rays are also drawn at angles of incidence of 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 and 80 degrees. A ray box is used to produced the incident ray at the various angles. The path of the refracted rays are marked and the angle of refraction is measured for each angle of incidence. Sin(i) values are plotted on the y-axis, sin(r) values are plotted on the x-axis. A best-fit line is a straight line nearly through the origin. The refractive index of the glass block n is found from the slope of the graph.

The data I used is:

i-values = {30,40,50,60,70,80}

r-values = {19,27,32,36,40,44}

My textbook says to force the best-fit line through the origin.

But my understanding is: If the data points are fairly linear in that they have a correlation coefficient close to 1 and the line does not go through the origin it means that during the experiment the normal was off by about 1 or 2 degrees.

If this is so then taking the slope of the best-fit line not forced through the origin would take this into account.

What are peoples thoughts on this ?

If the data show good linearity and the difference between the forced and non-forced slope is say 1.46 and 1.38 which slope should be taken as the refractive index, the forced or the non-forced ?

Also is my understanding reasonable that the reason for the best-fit line missing the origin slightly is that the normal was off slightly ?

Comment: What graph? What are you plotting? You should explain i.e., what is on the X and Y axes. You should also explain the objective of the experiment - it may not be immediately obvious to all who read this.

Answer (score 2):

The line may not pass through the origin due to a systematic error, and in that case forcing it to pass through the origin will give a poorer fit and leave the systematic error unidentified. So in general I would not force the fit to pass through the origin.

Comment: That's what I was thinking myself. The graph identifies a sytematic error. One must identify the source of the error and then go back and gather the data again. The best-fit line should better approach the origin. That's my understanding anyway.

Comment: Would it not have been a good thing to have obtained $r$ for $i=0°$ as one of your experimental values?

Comment: @PhilipWood Well these are not my data , but yes that would have been useful.